# Drawing from a list of vertices using OpenTK/MonoTouch?

Tags: c#, opengl, xamarin.ios, opentk

This is a very simple and straight forward question, I realize that, but I've been mulling over google searches and haven't really found an answer to what I thought would be a simple question.

I have a class called vertex, defined as such:

```
class Vertex
{
   Vector3 position;
   Vector3 normal;
   Vector2 uv;
}
```

And I hav ea list of Vertex's. My question is, how can I draw this list of vertices out using OpenTK (1.1)?

As I've said, I've tried google searches and such but haven't found anything remotely helpful. I was hoping I could at least find simple sample code for drawing a polygon but no luck either.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll find examples in the source code repository here:

http://opentk.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/opentk/trunk/Source/Examples/OpenGL/

Here is the documentation that refers to drawing:

http://www.opentk.com/doc/chapter/2/opengl/geometry/drawing

For general OpenGL tutorials check out NeHe:

http://nehe.gamedev.net/